# In Odoo, How to develop a custom condition when creating or updating a record from any model?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-15

There is company_id field in res.partner model.
I also have a relational field named 'property_account_payable_id'

```
property_account_payable_id = fields.Many2one('account.account')
```

property_account_payable_id field is related to 'account.account' model.

I want to make a condition where on creating or updating a partner will check if 'res.partner' model's company_id is same as relational 'account.account' model's company_id.
This is not only for 'res.partner' model, I want to make this condition globally on all the models where there is own company_id and relational table company_id field.

How can I achieve this in odoo?